# Common Lisp: How to return a list without the nth element of a given list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've a question, how to return a list without the nth element of a given list? E.g., given list: `(1 2 3 2 4 6)`, and given `n = 4`, in this case the return list should be `(1 2 3 4 6)`.

Comment: If this is homework, please add the "homework" tag.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Lisp homework? I think not

Comment: @SethCarnegie, it's rare, but it happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple recursive solution:

```
(defun remove-nth (n list)
  (declare
    (type (integer 0) n)
    (type list list))
  (if (or (zerop n) (null list))
    (cdr list)
    (cons (car list) (remove-nth (1- n) (cdr list)))))
```

This will share the common tail, except in the case where the list has `n` or more elements, in which case it returns a new list with the same elements as the provided one.

Comment: +1: I wrote procedural `DO` based version manually building the result and it was (on SBCL) 4 times faster and half consing compared to the `remove-if` approach, but this is much cleaner and with the same performance...

Comment: @6502: If you're concerned about performance, did you try using `delete-if` instead of `remove-if`? On CCL, this destructive version is an order of magnitude faster and less consing with the default `optimize` settings and without further tweaks. (Tested with a list of 100k elements, dropping an element in the middle.)

Comment: @danlei: that means changing the original problem. This versions is non-destructive and shares the tail. To make a non-destructive version out of a destructive one you need to make a full copy first and then my guess is that the end result of copy / destructive version will cons more and will be slower.

Comment: @6502, the original question doesn't say if modifying the input list is forbidden or if the output list should share structure.  I generally prefer my functions to be nondestructive and share structure, but I don't see anything in the question prohibiting modifying the input.  C and Java programmers would likely find that to be a natural thing to do.  And in some situations, the shared tail might be a liability instead of an asset.

Comment: @danlei, if your list has 100k elements, it might be time to consider a more complex data structure ;)

Comment: @6502 Yes, it's a change in semantics compared to the provided solutions, but I agree with @Samuel in that it's perfectly compatible with the given specification. You're right, making this destructive version non-destructive using `copy-list` would neutralize the performance/consing advantage. However, if one knows what they're doing, resorting to destructive operations is a legitimate means to improve performance. I just wanted to point out another possibility that improves perfomance of my original solution by an order of magnitude by just changing a single word.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Well, measuring with a smaller list inside a loop maybe would've been more realistic, but I was lazy. :)

Comment: By the way: While I prefer having non-destructive functions by default, destructive versions are, in a way, the more general solution. You could turn any destructive operation into a non-destructive one by copying its argument – Making a non-destructive function destructive, however, usually takes a rewrite. (This is just meant to be a side note, not an argument for having destructive operations as an default in general.)

Comment: I agree that "internally destructive, externally pure" approach of writing functions (like my `do`/`(setf (cdr x) y)`) doesn't scale by composition. I'm no Common Lisp expert, but as the problem is stated however ("return a list without the nth element of a given list") I'd assume that a destructive operation would be surprising... but may be it's me (and I've been for example bitten in the past by `sort` being destructive and not being named `nsort`).

Comment: actually, I don't think this is right. The OP clearly indicates 1-based indexing; and if `n > length(lst)`, *then* what happens?? (the last sentence is wrong too).

Comment: @WillNess, in what way does the question indicate 1-based indexing?  When index 4 is removed, the fifth element disappears.  You're right about n > length though, I'm not sure how I missed that.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard quote: " E.g., given list: (1 2 3 2 4 6), and given n = 4, in this case the return list should be (1 2 3 4 6)." With 0-based indexing, the result would have to be `(1 2 3 2 6)` which is what your code produces, too. The last sentence should speak of "less than `n` elements". Small stuff, off-by-1 &the like. :)

Comment: also, what if the list is circular and `n` is negative? (and for destructive versions, what if `n` is greater than the circular list's period?)

Comment: @WillNess, you're right about the 1-based indexing in the question too; some part of my brain refused to read it correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Using `remove-if`:

```
(defun foo (n list)
  (remove-if (constantly t) list :start (1- n) :count 1))
```

`butlast`/`nthcdr` solution (corrected):

```
(defun foo (n list)
  (append (butlast list (1+ (- (length list) n))) (nthcdr n list)))
```

Or, maybe more readable:

```
(defun foo (n list)
  (append (subseq list 0 (1- n)) (nthcdr n list)))
```

Using `loop`:

```
(defun foo (n list)
  (loop for elt in list
        for i from 1
        unless (= i n) collect elt))
```

Comment: Btw: Interesting, how I got two upvotes for a wrong solution. Having worked almost exclusively with Haskell for a few months, I initially used `butlast` like `take` in the `butlast`/`nthcdr` solution. (Thinking along the lines of `take n xs ++ drop (n+1) xs`)

Comment: I upvoted you for the reason that I've been writing in Haskell lately, and mentally did the same thing...oops

Comment: @jcc333 Great minds err alike? ;) Anyway, it's corrected now – no harm done.

Comment: or with nconc: `(defun nfoo (n ls) (nconc (butlast ...) ...))`. But the check for `n > (length ls)` case is missing. Only the `loop` version is working then.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, if this was to be used in a library, or in situations where proper inputs are not guaranteed, one should maybe add an `(assert (<= 1 n (length list)))`, or make the implementations just return the original list. (BTW, on CCL the `remove-if` and `loop` versions both do the latter.)

Comment: what's a CCL? (forgive the ignorance) :) I tested in CLisp; only `loop` worked properly.

Comment: @WillNess A Common Lisp implementation: http://www.clozure.com/clozurecl.html (The successor of Coral Common Lisp, the later Macintosh Common Lisp.)

Comment: thanks! thought of something just now - for circular lists your `loop` version won't terminate. I guess it means that only the simple recursive *copying-sharing* version of Samuel E. W. will be the right answer, after the one-off error is corrected there.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, to make this work with circular lists (in an eager laguage like CL), Samuel's solution would probably be the most straightforward approach. I disagree about my solutions being incorrect, though – By that reasoning `remove-if` itself would have to be considered incorrect, since it doesn't terminate despite its given `:start` and `:count` (woudn't work with `:end` either) parameters. Rather, I would think of circular lists as a special case. (In fact, per the standard, circular lists aren't *proper lists* at all.)

Comment: The last 2 (append and loop) are most readable and intuitive. An overdose in Haskell produces weird stuff like the other ones :)

Comment: @BitTickler Hehehe, thanks, I'm recovering. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an interesting approach. It replaces the nth element of a list with a new symbol and then removes that symbol from the list. I haven't considered how (in)efficient it is though!

```
(defun remove-nth (n list)
    (remove (setf (nth n list) (gensym)) list))
```

Comment: (defun delete-nth (n list)
        (delete (setf (nth n list) (gensym)) list))

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(loop :for i :in '(1 2 3 2 4 6) ; the list
              :for idx :from 0
              :unless (= 3 idx) :collect i) ; except idx=3
;; => (1 2 3 4 6)
```

loop macro can be very useful and effective in terms of generated code by lisp compiler and macro expander.

Test run and apply macroexpand above code snippet.

Comment: Please explain that how your answer will help to solve the problem, and just dont give code only answer without context

Comment: Sorry, I thought the context is already given by the question.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more general function:

```
(defun remove-by-position (pred lst)
  (labels ((walk-list (pred lst idx)
             (if (null lst)
                 lst
                 (if (funcall pred idx)
                     (walk-list pred (cdr lst) (1+ idx))
                     (cons (car lst) (walk-list pred (cdr lst) (1+ idx)))))))
    (walk-list pred lst 1)))
```

Which we use to implement desired remove-nth:

```
(defun remove-nth (n list)
  (remove-by-position (lambda (i) (= i n)) list))
```

And the invocation:

```
(remove-nth 4 '(1 2 3 2 4 6))
```

Edit: Applied remarks from Samuel's comment.

Comment: Interesting, and something I think I've wanted before.  I'd suggest renaming your `remove-nth` to... something else... `remove-by-position`?  And defining remove-nth `(defun remove-nth (n list) (remove-by-position (lambda (i) (= i n)) list)`.

Answer (score 1):

A destructive version, the original list will be modified (except when n < 1),

```
(defun remove-nth (n lst)
  (if (< n 1) (cdr lst)
    (let* ((p (nthcdr (1- n) lst))
           (right (cddr p)))
      (when (consp p)
        (setcdr p nil))
      (nconc lst right))))
```

That's elisp but I think those are standard lispy functions.

Answer (score 1):

For all you haskellers out there, there is no need to twist your brains :)

```
(defun take (n l)
  (subseq l 0 (min n (length l))))
(defun drop (n l)
  (subseq l n))
(defun remove-nth (n l)
  (append (take (- n 1) l)
      (drop n l)))
```

Answer (score 0):

My horrible elisp solution:

```
(defun without-nth (list n)
  (defun accum-if (list accum n)
    (if (not list)
        accum
          (accum-if (cdr list) (if (eq n 0) accum (cons (car list) accum)) 
            (- n 1))))
  (reverse (accum-if list '() n)))

(without-nth '(1 2 3) 1)
```

Should be easily portable to Common Lisp.

Comment: In Common Lisp local functions are introduced with FLET and LABELS.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution will be as follows.

```
(defun remove-nth (n lst)
    (append (subseq lst 0 (- n 1)) (subseq lst n (length lst)))
)
```